# What does dashed blue lines overlay with thick faded blue lines mean in an aeronautical-chart?

Tags: airspace, aeronautical-charts

[image: screenshot from SkyVector - Ankara/Turkey]

By looking at the dashed blue lines overlay with thick faded blue lines, can we say these are Class D airspace and Class E airspace above 1200' AGL?

Comment: Aeronautical charts are unfortunately not standardized worldwide, this is SkyVector's rendition.

Comment: @falstro, moreover, I think SkyVector is not even completely consistent with itself between different parts of the world, likely because their sources are not either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Overall: Turkey system may be specific**

Turkey is not integrated in the Single European Sky. The harmonization and simplification of airspace classification going on in many European countries is not applicable to Turkey, so we are in a kind of specific case which requires more research effort to understand it. See this [Eurocontrol report](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/content/documents/official-documents/reports/2013-lssip-turkey.pdf).

From the documentation I happen to read, the Turkish airspace system is seemingly as efficient as another and, for instance, is more efficient in releasing military areas (SUA) to civil use when possible.

I wasn't able to find any description. If you can register to the [Turkey AIP](http://ssd.dhmi.gov.tr/ANSLogin.aspx), you should have access to the relevant data.

**Additional information from ICAO GIS Viewer**

The same area than the one in the question in the [ICAO viewer](http://gis.icao.int/icaoviewer/). I have selected different layers (a bit of learning would be needed to understand all of them), and highlighted data for three areas:

[image]

I selected only the lower space, else the viewer display is really cluttered because the developers haven't done a great job in managing label locations. The areas are:

- Yellow: ANKARA [ACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_Control_Center) SCTR 8 LOWER. GND to FL325.
- Blue:  ESENBOGA [CTLZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_zone). SFC to 4,500 AMSL
- Green: AKINCI CTLZ. SFC to 12,000 AMSL

You can click on an area and a list of descriptions is displayed. You can browse this list with the arrows on the popup title bar (multiple areas may be relevant for the point you clicked). For AKINCI CTLZ:

[image]

Which class of airspace are they? Which rules are associated with them? I've really no idea and the legend in the viewer doesn't help:

[image]

**Special use airspace (SUA)**

I think it's still reasonable to interpret for non-professional purposes the area names this way (LT being the ICAO prefix for Turkey):

- LTD: Danger (e.g. LDT-20)
- LTR: Restricted or Regulated (e.g. LTR-30)
- LTP: Prohibited (e.g. LTP-0097)
- LTM: Military (e.g. LTM-LTANKZ1).

So these are [SUA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_use_airspace).

**Documents that may be interesting**

- [ATC Prosedür ve Operasyonları Kılavuzu](http://www.ivaotr.org/downloads/documents/other/APOM-TR%20Rev.4.pdf) from IVAO Turkey.

**Get additional help**

You may also want to look at [PPRuNE](http://www.pprune.org/) which is a discussion board for pilots. You'll find pilots flying in/to Turkey, and they may provide you more information.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are probably in hundreds of meters. So 120/SFC would be surface to 12,000 meters.

Turkey does not have the kind of airspace classification that we do in the United States. The dashed blue lines probably just mean that it is controlled airspace. You can see that there are frequencies listed. So, what that means, is that you have to call on those frequencies to get clearance to enter those areas.

Comment: Albeit this is not an authoritative reference, [IVAO Turkey](http://www.ivaotr.org/about) specifies altitude in feet likely because Turkey ATC also uses feet.

Comment: @mins, you are right. Turkey ATC also uses feet.

Comment: @enginbulanık Maybe, but in that case the controlled zones seem kind of illogical. Why would you have a controlled zone going from only surface to 4500 feet? That makes no sense. If it was meters, I could see that.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Actually there are other areas above this one: ANKARA TCA LOWER SCTR (4,500 to FL145) and ANKARA TCA UPPER SCTR (FL145 to FL240). This can be seen in the ICAO viewer.

Comment: @mins  Ok, if that is the case, then it makes sense, but those other areas are not on the chart shown in the question.